# Ghostscript execution error on server

Tags: asp.net, ghostscript

I am converting PDF file into image by using GhostScript

Ghostscript can not execute command on a web site over IIS but works fine in my local computer and server side with the Visual Studio.

The error message is:

**Failed to process GhostScript command.**

I guess there should be some dll allocation to somewhere but i can not find exactly.

i granted IIS_WPG user(since i am using Server 2003 64 bit) to Full Control for Ghost Script's dll files but i did not solve my problem.

Can you help me?

Comment: You could try to use https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET a managed Ghostscript wrapper for .NET which uses API calls to a dll instead of .exe.

Comment: Yes, RasterizerSample works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think on 2003 boxes, Network Service is the default user account.  Check the application pool that the site runs under and see who the account is.  Then make sure the executable is in a directory that the user account can access. Also make sure that the .ps file that GS is processing is in a directory that the user can access.  Then make sure that the user account can write to the directory that GS is set to output to.

Comment: Network Service is the account and i granted it in everywhere except the .ps file since i can not find it. I have gsdll32.dll,gsdll32.lib and Cyotek Ghost Script libraries.